# accessing NSUserDefaults within cellForRow(at:IndexPath) in Swift, memory usage

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Is it memory intensive to retrieve data from `NSUserDefaults` within the `cellForRow(at:IndexPath` method? Code shown below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let recentFavorite = UserDefaults.standard.string("recentlyStoredFavorite")
  if self.favorite == recentFavorite {
    cell.imgForFavorite = self.imgForFavorite
  }
}
```

Or should I save the value from `UserDefaults` in `viewWillAppear` and use that within `cellForRow`?

Please help me understand the memory implications of both the choices.

Comment: Don't do that. A potential memory usage issue is negligible over the performance issue to read the same value again and again. A very efficient way is to add a property `isFavorite` in the data model and set it while populating the data source array.

Comment: @vadian But it's a simple dictionary lookup. I truly doubt there is any relevant performance issue here. But yes, storing the value in a class property may be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple

> At runtime, you use UserDefaults objects to read the defaults that
>   your app uses from a user’s defaults database. UserDefaults caches the
>   information to avoid having to open the user’s defaults database each
>   time you need a default value.

You should be 'ok' to retrieve the info in cellForRow, as its likely sitting in a dictionary in memory (assumption), fetched by the key you provide, however to vadian's point, you could just put it in a model or property and eliminate the assumption.

Also, consider if that data will be changed by another process and if you need to observe UserDefaults key.